# How to read SOAP messages and create variables in Azure API management policies

Tags: azure, policy

Sample SOAP message is below :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://TempNameSpace">
            <Name>ABCD</Name>
            <Age>25</Age>
        </ns0:Root>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I want to read Age field from above SOAP message and store it in a variable in API outbound policy.
Please help.

Comment: FYI, I know how to access it inside liquid template. I need help in reading it outside set-body policy to store in a variable.

Comment: I found a work around. First convert the SOAP req to JSON using xml-to-json policy. Then read the JSON elements using context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true) ["s$Envelope"]["s$Body"]["ns0$Root"]["Age"].ToString() and store in a variable. This is working now. If anyone has other suggestions, please share.